# bug in jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have used the jquery form validation from this site http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/. In this site validation works when the field values are empty. I need it to work if i set values to the form fields for example the value for the email field is `Email Address`. How can i modify that?. The internal script that i have used is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() { alert("submitted!"); }
});

$().ready(function() {
    // validate the comment form when it is submitted
    $("#commentForm").validate();

    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#signupForm").validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: "required",
            lastname: "required",
            username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            confirm_password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                equalTo: "#password"
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            topic: {
                required: "#newsletter:checked",
                minlength: 2
            },
            agree: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
            lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
            username: {
                required: "Please enter a username",
                minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
            },
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            confirm_password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
                equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
            },
            email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            agree: "Please accept our policy"
        }
    });

    // propose username by combining first- and lastname
    $("#username").focus(function() {
        var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
        var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
        if(firstname && lastname && !this.value) {
            this.value = firstname + "." + lastname;
        }
    });

    //code to hide topic selection, disable for demo
    var newsletter = $("#newsletter");
    // newsletter topics are optional, hide at first
    var inital = newsletter.is(":checked");
    var topics = $("#newsletter_topics")[inital ? "removeClass" : "addClass"]("gray");
    var topicInputs = topics.find("input").attr("disabled", !inital);
    // show when newsletter is checked
    newsletter.click(function() {
        topics[this.checked ? "removeClass" : "addClass"]("gray");
        topicInputs.attr("disabled", !this.checked);
    });
});
</script>
```

This is my html

```
<form class="cmxform" id="signupForm" method="get" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Validating a complete form</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
            <input id="firstname" name="firstname" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
            <input id="lastname" name="lastname" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input id="username" name="username" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="confirm_password">Confirm password</label>
            <input id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" type="password" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="agree">Please agree to our policy</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="agree" name="agree" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="newsletter">I'd like to receive the newsletter</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="newsletter" name="newsletter" />
        </p>
        <fieldset id="newsletter_topics">
            <legend>Topics (select at least two) - note: would be hidden when newsletter isn't selected, but is visible here for the demo</legend>
            <label for="topic_marketflash">
                <input type="checkbox" id="topic_marketflash" value="marketflash" name="topic" />
                Marketflash
            </label>
            <label for="topic_fuzz">
                <input type="checkbox" id="topic_fuzz" value="fuzz" name="topic" />
                Latest fuzz
            </label>
            <label for="topic_digester">
                <input type="checkbox" id="topic_digester" value="digester" name="topic" />
                Mailing list digester
            </label>
            <label for="topic" class="error">Please select at least two topics you'd like to receive.</label>
        </fieldset>
        <p>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Please see my edited code for html

Answer (score 1):

So my understanding from your question is that if they leave the field with the default value, e.g. "Email Address", you want that to error.  You'll need to create your own custom validation method, using the [addMethod](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage) function.  Then you refer to that method in your options.  I think something like this is the correct syntax:

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkdefault", function (value, element, params) {
        if (params[0] == params[1] || params[0].length === 0) {
        // user hasn't changed value from the default, or they've left it completely blank
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });

email: {
// pass an array of params, first one is the field value, second is your default text
   checkdefault: [$("#email").val(), 'Email Address'],
   email: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have set you values, call $("#signupForm").validate() if you set your values from javascript. If you do it with server side technology validate on document.Ready()